# Exclude a solution in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am using the default pipeline for several solutions:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - 'develop'

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

The 'OldPlatform.sln' file must be excluded. How can I exclude a solution? Can I filter the 'solution' variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The 'OldPlatform.sln' file must be excluded. How can I exclude a solution? Can I filter the 'solution' variable?

You could make a pattern negative by prefixing it with `'-:'`. Example: `**\*.sln;-:**\*.Tests.lsn`.

So, you could set the variable `solution` like:

```
variables:
  solution: '**\*.sln;-:**\OldPlatform.sln'
```

Note: Make sure the path of the solution `OldPlatform.sln` is correct.

You could check [this thread](https://blogs.infosupport.com/tfs2015-build-tasks-the-wildcard-format-explained/) for some more details.